# Deep Copy a .NET Class Instance Without Serialization

Tags: .net, instance, deep-copy

I am using an instance class from a third-party DLL, and I need to do a deep copy on a particular instance.  The class is not marked as `Serializable`, and therefore I can not use [this suggested method using `BinaryFormatter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically).

How can I get a deep copy of this object without using serialization?

Comment: "Copying" does not necessarily make sense for all classes.

Comment: @Mehrdad Please elaborate, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: The canonical example is a Singleton class. You shouldn't (and shouldn't be able to) copy it.

Comment: @Mehrdad I understand what you mean now.  I am convinced that the absence of `Serializable` in this case was a lack of foresight with the API devs.

Comment: In addition, making deep copies of things like database connections, network connections, or transactions can cause massive lossage.

Comment: You can use a mapper, i suggest UltraMapper https://github.com/maurosampietro/UltraMapper

Comment: Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52097307/4707576): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52097307/4707576 about: Cloning objects without Serialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using [Copyable](http://ox.no/software/copyable) with great success.  It uses reflection under the hood. It is open-sourced. Be sure to read *Limitations and pitfalls* to see if you can use it.

Comment: I believe this will work for me, thanks!  I understand the pitfalls, and thankfully what I am currently working with has absolutely no unmanaged resources.  Thanks again, I'll let you know how it works out.

Comment: (updated your answer to include SEO-link, and confirmed that library uses reflection)

Comment: One caveat not mentioned with *Copyable* is that classes like it don't know anything about outside references into a data structure.  Suppose, for example, that within a class there's a reference to a single-element array of String, and suppose that every second some other class puts the current time of day into the first (only) element of that array.  A clone of the original class object would contain a string with the time of day the object was copied, rather than a continuously-changing one.

Comment: You can use a mapper, i suggest UltraMapper https://github.com/maurosampietro/UltraMapper. It uses ExpressionTrees instead of Reflection and thus it is 1000x faster than reflection

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion is to use Json serialization (which uses reflection, and doesn't rely on the `[Serializable]` attribute) to serialize and deserialize into a copy. For example, using the Json.Net library:

```
var copiedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Snapshot>(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sourceSnapshotObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't (or perhaps shouldn't is what I'm looking for).

If the class is not designed to be serialized, and it does not provide you a means to clone it (i.e. in the form of a clone or copy method) then you cannot easily automatically do this. (And in addition, if this facility is not provided, then you probably should not do this, as the class is probably not designed with this type of usage in mind.)

However, if you really want to do it and you're in a full trust environment, then of course you can do some dirty stuff using `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` and then using reflection to copy the field values from one object to the other. But this is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think you should see Kenny's answer.