# Deep cloning objects from Autorest generated code

Tags: c#, serialization, swagger, autorest

I am using Autorest to generate code to call my api.

I want to use the following in my unit tests

```
    private JobHeaderRequestObject MakeRequestFromResponse(JobHeaderResponseObject InResponseObject)
{
    // make use of the fact that in the server side code we know  JobHeaderResponseObject inherits from JobHeaderRequestObject 
    return MySerializer.DeepConvert<JobHeaderResponseObject,JobHeaderRequestObject>(InResponseObject);
}


internal class MySerializer
{

    public static T2 DeepConvert<T1,T2>(T1 obj)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return (T2)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

However when I try to run this code I get an error mentioning

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
```

indicating that the type

```
is not marked as serializable
```

I don't want to go through the generated code adding the attribute

[Serializable]

to each type, because the code will get overwritten the next time I generate.

I looked at [this issue on the Git Hub project](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/2773) and it mentions

> If the swagger spec has a model definition like this

```
{
  "Foo": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "age": {
        "type": "number"
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

> then Autorest generated SDKs should be able to serialize and
>   deserialize (round trip) the unknown properties correctly.
>
> Generated C# clients support this today by having a Dictionary AdditionalProperties.

So now I am trying to understand what an Autorest spec is and how I set it up.

In startup.cs I have in Configure

```
            app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.RouteTemplate =
                "api-docs/{documentName}/swagger.json";
        });



        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            //Include virtual directory if site is configured so
            c.RoutePrefix = "api-docs";
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("./v1/swagger.json", "Api v1");

        });
```

In ConfigureServices I have

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.OperationFilter<AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "My API",
                Description = "ASP.NET Core Web API",
                TermsOfService = "None",
                Contact = new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Contact
                {
                    Name = "MyName",
                    Email = "MyEmail@Mydomain.com"
                }


            });

            c.EnableAnnotations();
            c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            c.ParameterFilter<SwaggerEnumParameterFilter>();
            c.SchemaFilter<SwaggerEnumFilter>();
        });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935056/cloning-objects-without-serialization?rq=1

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/2773

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/autorest

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/autorest/blob/master/docs/user/cli.md

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: https://support.reprezen.com/support/solutions/articles/6000162892-support-for-additionalproperties-in-swagger-2-0-schemas